# Magento2: how to display small images of product collection data?

Tags: magento2, product-images, small-image

how to display small images of product collection data?

Magento 2.0

Comment: could you add more detail about your question, what you are trying to do and what have you done so far ?

Comment: I want to display small images on product view page  @Naveed

Comment: I have product collection data but I have not idea how to display product images. @Naveed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get collection of products in Block

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository;

class Products extends Template
{    
   protected $_productCollectionFactory;
   protected $_productImageHelper;
   protected $_productRepository;

   public function __construct(
        Context $context,        
        CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
        Image $productImageHelper,
        ProductRepository $productRepository,
    )
    {    
        $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
        $this->_productImageHelper = $productImageHelper;
        $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
    public function getProductBySku($sku)
    {
        return $this->_productRepository->get($sku);
    }

     public function resizeImage($product,$imageId, $width, $height = null)
        {
            $_product = $this->getProductBySku($product->getSku());
            $resizedImage = $this->_productImageHelper
                               ->init($_product, $imageId)
                               ->constrainOnly(TRUE)
                               ->keepAspectRatio(TRUE)
                               ->keepTransparency(TRUE)
                               ->keepFrame(FALSE)
                               ->resize($width, $height);
            return $resizedImage;
    }

    public function getProductCollection(){

        $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('status',\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
        $collection->addAttributeToSort('name', 'ASC');
        return $collection;
    }
}
```

Call collection in phtml file and display images like below

```
<?php $productCollection = $block->getProductCollection(); ?>

<?php foreach ($productCollection as $_product) { 

$resizedImageUrl = $block->resizeImage($_product, 'product_base_image', 80, 80)->getUrl();  ?>
echo "<img src=".$resizedImageUrl."/>";

}
?>
```